# STRICT_TRANS_TABLES : Is there a performance interest?

Tags: mysql, innodb, sql-mode

I am not able to find a good article which can say STRICT_TRANS_TABLES is best or not for performance (insert)?

More generally, if you have a good article which explain in terms of performance the different sql mode... I am interested in.

Comment: It's not a "performance" option, it's about data integrity and correctness.

Comment: Define "performance".  I mean, if one considers the fact that strict SQL modes will abort insertions in more situations than non-strict modes, one could conclude that "performance" has suffered; otherwise I cannot imagine there is a material difference in insert speed.

Comment: Yes Performance was for Speed. Thank you for your answers.